# Duvida: como utilizar scripts python para web?

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-aws, opencv

Quero fazer uma aplicação web que irá ler cores em RGB de logotipos e criar sugestões de escalas de cores para websites.

O algoritmo será em python, utilizando OpenCV.

O cliente sobe a imagem >  a imagem é lida pelo algoritmo > o servidor retorna para o cliente os resultados.

Minhas dúvidas:

1. Como comunicar o lado do cliente com o algoritmo? Eu realmente não faço ideia de como estruturar isto.
2. Como eu incluo o módulo OpenCV no Python no servidor? Eu instalei ele na minha máquina, mas precisaria instalá-lo também no servidor, certo? (Considerar o uso do AWS)

Comment: Você já consegue fazer o processamento localmente?

Comment: Use um framework como django ou flask, veja esse [exemplo minimalista com flask.](https://github.com/desertfury/flask-opencv-streaming)

Comment: O Python "out of the box" não consegue se conectar com a Web assim. Você pode implementar um servidor web com ele ou pode utilizar um framework, assim como o @Sidon indicou assim. Particularmente, gosto do Django.

Comment: Obrigado! O exemplo em Flask ajuda bastante, vou verificar o Django também para ver o que me agrada mais. Quanto à questão do OpenCV quando eu publicar o app na web: como eu incluo o módulo no servidor?

Answer (score 2):

1 - Aconselharia você utilizar algum framework WEB tipo o Django, Flask algo do tipo, assim você pode programar de maneira mais fácil um "site" para fazer o upload dessa imagem.

2 - Usando o AWS você pode conectar via ssh na máquina e fazer a instalação dos pacotes necessários. É uma boa pratica você manter suas dependências em um arquivo (requirements.txt use o comando pip freeze > requirements.txt). O Heroku por exemplo procura por esse arquivo para instalar as dependências do seu projeto.